# Using i18next-resources-to-backend with React Native?

Tags: react-native, i18next, react-i18next

I'm currently trying to use i18next in React Native via react-i18next to fetch language from both back-end and local resources

My issue is while the backend fetch via `i18next-http-backend` works fine, the local resources via `i18next-resources-to-backend` is not working.

The current code is below:

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import {initReactI18next} from 'react-i18next';
import ChainedBackend from 'i18next-chained-backend';
import HttpBackend from 'i18next-http-backend';
import ResourceBackend from 'i18next-resources-to-backend';
import Axios from 'axios';

const EN = {
  sayHi: 'Say hi',
};

const VI = {
  sayHi: 'Xin chào',
};

i18n
  .use(ChainedBackend)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    compatibilityJSON: 'v3',
    react: {
      useSuspense: false,
    },
    lng: 'en',
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    load: 'languageOnly',
    backend: {
      backends: [
        HttpBackend,
        ResourceBackend({
          en: {
            translations: EN,
          },
          vi: {
            translations: VI,
          },
        }),
      ],
      backendOptions: [
        {
          loadPath: 'http://localhost:3001/translation/{{lng}}.json',
          parse: data => data,
          request: (options, url, payload, callback) => {
            Axios.get(url)
              .then(res => {
                callback(null, res);
              })
              .catch(e => {
                console.log(e);
                callback(e, null);
              });
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  });
```

Is there something wrong in my code?

Comment: what’s the log output when setting debug: true ?

Comment: same problem for me with react-native

Comment: I have checked and found that the resources from `i18next-http-backend` will overwrite those from `i18next-resources-to-backend`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but for any who have the same problem:

```
ResourceBackend({
          en: {
            translations: EN,
          },
          vi: {
            translations: VI,
          },
        }),
```

[The default namespace of i18next is 'translation' and not 'translations'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Xkya.png)